# Find unique entries in otherwise identical rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I am currently trying to find a way to find unique column values in otherwise duplicate rows in a dataset.

My dataset has the following properties:

- The dataset's columns comprise an identifier variable (ID) and a large number of response variables (x1 - x*n*).
- Each row should represent one individual, meaning the values in the ID column should all be unique (and not repeated).
- Some rows are duplicated, with repeated entries in the ID column and *seemingly* identical response item values (x1 - x*n*). However, the dataset is too large to get a full overview over all variables.

As demonstrated in the code below, if rows are truly identical for all variables, then the duplicate row can be removed with the `dplyr::distinct()` function. In my case, not all "duplicate" rows are removed by `distinct()`, which can only mean that not all entries are identical.

**I want to find a way to identify which entries are unique in these otherwise duplicate rows.**

Example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df <- data.frame(
    "ID" = rep(1:3, each = 2),
    "x1" = rep(4:6, each = 2),
    "x2" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"),
    "x3" = c(7, 10, 8, 8, 9, 11),
    "x4" = rep(letters[4:6], each = 2),
    "x5" = c("x", "p", "y", "y", "z", "q"),
    "x6" = rep(letters[7:9], each = 2)
)

# The dataframe with all entries
df

A data.frame: 6 × 7
ID  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
1   4   a   7   d   x   g
1   4   a   10  d   p   g
2   5   b   8   e   y   h
2   5   b   8   e   y   h
3   6   c   9   f   z   i
3   6   d   11  f   q   i


# The dataframe
df %>% 
# with duplicates removed
distinct() %>%
# filtered for columns only containing duplicates in the ID column
janitor::get_dupes(ID)

ID  dupe_count  x1  x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
1   2           4   a   7   d   x   g
1   2           4   a   10  d   p   g
3   2           6   c   9   f   z   i
3   2           6   d   11  f   q   i
```

In the example above I demonstrate how `dplyr::distinct()` will remove fully duplicate rows (ID = 2), but not rows that are different in some columns (rows where ID = 1 and 3, and columns x2, x3 and x5).

What I want is an overview over which columns that are not duplicates for each value:

```
df %>% 
distinct() %>%
janitor::get_dupes(ID) %>% 
# Here I want a way to find columns with unidentical entries:
find_nomatch()

ID x2 x3 x5
 1     7  x
 1    10  p
 3  c  9  z
 3  d 11  q
```

Comment: You can use group_by and check all but ID: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>%  janitor::get_dupes(-c(ID))`

Comment: @CIAndrews This will return the fully duplicated rows, not the ones that has unique values somewhere. I have updated my post to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` alternative. Coerce data frame to a `data.table` (`setDT`). Melt data to long format (`melt(df, id.vars = "ID")`).

Within each group defined by 'ID' and 'variable' (corresponding to the columns in the wide format) (`by = .(ID, variable)`), count number of unique values (`uniqueN(value)`) and check if it's equal to the number of rows in the subgroup (`== .N`). If so (`if`), select the entire subgroup (`.SD`).

Finally, reshape the data back to wide format (`dcast`).

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
d = melt(df, id.vars = "ID")
dcast(d[ , if(uniqueN(value) == .N) .SD, by = .(ID, variable)], ID + rowid(ID, variable) ~ variable)
#    ID ID_1   x2 x3 x5
# 1:  1    1 <NA>  7  x
# 2:  1    2 <NA> 10  p
# 3:  3    1    c  9  z
# 4:  3    2    d 11  q
```

Comment: Thanks, for your solution. It worked like a charm. However, I am trying to undertstand what the code actually do, as I am not very familiar with these functions or the terms you use. Would you care to elaborate what you mean by "melted to long format, filtered and cast back to wide"?

Comment: @PålBjartan For a general article about data in a long (tidy) format vs. in a wide (untidy) format, see [Tidy Data by Hadley Wickham](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). More specifically applying this concept using `data.table` functions, see [Efficient reshaping using data.tables](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html). For a more general understanding of `data.table` syntax, please start with the vignette [Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

A bit more simple than yours I think:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df <- data.frame(
    "ID" = rep(1:3, each = 2),
    "x1" = rep(4:6, each = 2),
    "x2" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "d"),
    "x3" = c(7, 10, 8, 8, 9, 11),
    "x4" = rep(letters[4:6], each = 2),
    "x5" = c("x", "p", "y", "y", "z", "q"),
    "x6" = rep(letters[7:9], each = 2)
)

d <- df %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  janitor::get_dupes(ID) 

d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  # Check for each id which row elements are different from the of the first
  group_map(\(.x, .id) apply(.x, 1, \(.y) .x[1, ] != .y))%>% 
  do.call(what = cbind) %>% # Bind results for all ids 
  apply(1, any) %>% # return true if there are differences anywhere
  c(T, .) %>% # Keep id column 
  `[`(d, .)
#>   ID x2 x3 x5
#> 1  1  a  7  x
#> 2  1  a 10  p
#> 3  3  c  9  z
#> 4  3  d 11  q
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit**

```r
d %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  # Check for each id which row elements are different from the of the first
  group_map(\(.x, .id) apply(.x, 1, \(.y) !Vectorize(identical)(unlist(.x[1, ]), .y))) %>% 
  do.call(what = cbind) %>% # Bind results for all ids 
  apply(1, any) %>% # return true if there are differences anywhere
  c(T, .) %>% # Keep id column 
  `[`(d, .)
#>   ID x2 x3 x5
#> 1  1  a  7  x
#> 2  1  a 10  p
#> 3  3  c  9  z
#> 4  3  d 11  q
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works like a charm on the small example I posted. However, when I try it on my real dataset I get an error message: `Error: Can't combine `..1` <character> and `..2` <double>.` Your example is, admittedly, a bit over my head, so I am having trouble breaking down what might throw such an error.

Comment: Looking at this again after your comment, I saw that `NA`s could lead to problems under certain conditions. I edited the answer to include the revised piece of code. Unfortunately, that change makes it somewhat more unwieldy (`.x[1, ] != .y` was replaced with `!Vectorize(identical)(unlist(.x[1, ]), .y)`). Also, I don't think this will fix the error you encountered, but I cannot tell without a sample of the data causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this issue for some time and I found a solution, though it tooks more step than I would've though necessary. I can only presume there's a more elegant solution out there. Anyway, this should work:

```
df <- df %>%
distinct() %>%
janitor::get_dupes(ID) 

# Make vector of unique values from the duplicated ID values
l <- distinct(df, ID) %>% unlist()

# Lapply on each ID
df <- lapply(
    l, 
    function(x) {
        # Filter rows for the duplicated ID
        dplyr::filter(df, ID == x) %>%
        # Transpose dataframe (converts it into a matrix) 
        t() %>%
        # Convert back to data frame
        as.data.frame() %>%
        # Filter columns that are not identical
        dplyr::filter(!if_all(everything(), ~ . == V1)) %>%
        # Transpose back
        t() %>%
        # Convert back to data frame
        as.data.frame()
    }
) %>% 
# Bind the dataframes in the list together
bind_rows() %>%
# Finally the columns are moved back in ascending order
relocate(x2, .before = x3)

#Remove row names (not necessary)
row.names(df) <- NULL

df

A data.frame: 4 × 3
x2  x3  x5
NA  7   x
NA  10  p
c   9   z
d   11  q
```

Feel free to comment